# How to install Function App Bindings on your own Docker Image

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions

I'm trying to setup an Azure Function App with my own Docker image (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=nodejs)

But I can't figure out how to install an Extension (e.g. CosmosDBTrigger, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/azure-functions/install-update-binding-extensions-manual)

Is it possible ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it to your project in Visual Studio, use package manager:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB -Version 3.0.4
```

Ensure your .csproj file has this package reference in it:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.4" />
```

If you need to add it manually, you can do so through Kudu which you access via https://[your-func-hostname].scm.azurewebsites.net - Full instructions [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions)

Adding manually to a deployed docker container can only be achieve when using persistent storage.

> You can use an app setting called WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE
>   to control whether or not the /home directory of your app is mapped to
>   Azure Storage. If you need files to be persisted in scale operations
>   or across restarts, you should add this app setting and set it to
>   "true". If you don't require file persistence, you can set this app
>   setting to false.
>
> The absence of this app setting will result in the setting being
>   "true". In other words, if this app setting does not exist in your
>   app, you will see the /home directory mapped to Azure Storage. The app
>   setting will be missing if you created your app while Web App for
>   Containers was in public preview or if someone has deleted the app
>   setting.
>
> Keep in mind that if you enable App Service Storage, when an Azure
>   Storage changeover occurs (which does happen periodically), your site
>   will restart when the storage volume changes.
>
> Note: If App Service Storage is not enabled, any files written into
>   the /home folder will not be persisted across instances (in the case
>   of a scale out) or across restarts.
>
> Even if storage persistence is disabled, the /home directory will be
>   mapped to Azure Storage in the Kudu (Advanced Tools) container. That
>   way, the /home/LogFiles directory will persist between restarts and
>   scale out operations in the Kudu container. Therefore, if you need to
>   get Docker logs or other logs, always use the Kudu Bash console
>   instead of using SSH to access your app's container. (See this for
>   more information on how to get the latest Docker logs from Kudu.)
>
> Note: If you set this app setting on an Azure App Service on Linux app
>   using a built-in image, it will have no impact.

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#NoStorage

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any `cmd` tab in Kudu. Only SSH and Bash. I can't access WebSSH (no ssh configured in my image). In Bash, I can't find my files. (`home/site/wwwroot` is empty)

Comment: Updated my answer with more info.  Package manager install of the dependency is my recommendation, but if you must change the deployed docker image then don't forget to update your source to reflect any changes.